# wagtail what has happened to wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/pages/_editor_css.html in version 4.2.2

Tags: wagtail

what has happened to wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/pages/_editor_css.html in version 4.2.2

we have template extract such as

```
{% extends "wagtailadmin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n wagtailadmin_tags modeladmin_tags %}

{% block titletag %}{{ view.get_meta_title }}{% endblock %}

{% block extra_css %}
    {{ block.super }}

    {% include "wagtailadmin/pages/_editor_css.html" %}
    {{ edit_handler.form.media.css }}

    {{ view.media.css }}
{% endblock %}
```

upgraded to wagtail 4.2.2 and getting error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist
```

I've seen this but what do we do

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-localize/issues/558

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was included into the core.css file as [part of this issue](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/8419). That doesn't really tell you how to update your current extra_css stanza - unless it just works with that line removed.